# PowerBI Embedded: Unable to use Import method with `Overwrite` option

Tags: c#, azure, powerbi

We are trying to integrate the Power BI embedded into our system based on the example provided on github:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/power-bi-embedded-integrate-report-into-web-app

Everything works fine except the Import with `Overwrite` option as explained on REST API:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt711504.aspx

Our case is we want to provide the update on pbix file, it's likely that users change pbix files continuously and then update that pbix back into PowerBI Embedded. We don't want to create new dataset whenever importing again on this case. That's why I tried the `Overwrite` option.

```
var import = await client.Imports.PostImportWithFileAsync(workspaceCollectionName, 
                                        workspaceId, fileStream, datasetName, "Overwrite");
```

But it seems this option is not working at the moment. If I try to import pbix file with new Dataset name. I got the error:

> Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'

If I try to import pbix file with the existing Dataset name. I got another error:

> Operation returned an invalid status code 'InternalServerError'

My expectation on `Overwrite` option is whenever we import with new dataset name, it still let import successfully. And whenever we import with existing dataset name, it will overwrite the current one.

Is this known bug?

Comment: Did you get an answer for it?

Comment: @Abhimanyu: This was a bug from Power BI Embedded, and it has been fixed.

Comment: strangely I am still getting the same issue! Any reference link for Bug Report?

Comment: @Abhimanyu: https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Cli/issues/9